# What is the difference between a controller of a directive and a controller of an app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the difference in functionality between a `controller` of a `directive` and a `controller` of `myApp` module defined in below snippet?

How exactly are we supposed to use `directive`'s `controller` and a module's controller, so that we make maximum utilization of the framework.

In case of differences, 1 or 2 examples showing the difference would really help a lot of newbies around.

**JS snippet**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('trialCtrl',function($scope){})
.directive('trial',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'CEAM'
    scope:{},
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){},
    controller:function(){},
    template:""
 }
})
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference? A controller is a controller.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: can u take look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLJos5CrqlJ8QNRFAtqu?p=preview) demo code and tell me how i can improve my code

Comment: out of scope here. Post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, maybe?

Comment: it's already [there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87799/shopping-cart-simulator) since yesterday, not even a single answer. Will really help me , if u could take a look

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This looks like example code and would therefore be off-topic for Code Review. CR is only for real-life, working code, rather than example/hypothetical code.

Comment: Also, without knowing the intention behind the code, it's not really possible to tell how to improve your usage of the technology. Some superfluous style nitpicks - yes. Idiomatic purity - less likely.

Comment: @Phrancis: that's why I added "maybe" :)

Comment: @Sergio: the code simulates a shopping cart, it is clearly mentioned in the [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87799/shopping-cart-simulator). It should be these kind of questions you guys should be expecting and solving more. These kind of code reviews can really help newbies to extract maximum out of whatever they are using.

Comment: @Phrancis:this platform is for learning and helping others to learn. So if you guys dont have the patience to understand the code and do the needful, its okay, i respect your decisions.

Comment: yeah, sorry, too busy here. :)

Comment: SO should have a DND tag for people who are busy, hmm tats sounds like a pretty good idea. Anyways carry on Sergio :)

Answer (score 2):

There is **no difference**, you could replace this "directive controller" with a string representing another controller.

**Example:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('trialCtrl',function($scope){})
.controller('myController',function($scope){})
.directive('trial',function(){
  return{
    // ...
    controller: 'myController'
    // ...
 }
})
```

**Note:** That's even cleaner to do it.

Comment: How about the `scope`? Is there any difference in the way `scope` works for both these `controller`s

Comment: The directive has his own scope, like a controller (note: there are some specificities, take a look at the documentation), but if your controller use `$scope` dependency injection, it can use the scope of this directive. Like if the directive was the parent of the controller.

Comment: :Can u take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLJos5CrqlJ8QNRFAtqu?p=preview) and suggest the required code changes to make better utilization of angularJS